# Linux: Using module functions

Tags: c, linux-kernel

Let's say I have a module which has this function my_open:

```
int my_open( struct inode *inode, struct file *filp ) {

   filp->private_data = //allocate private data 

   if( filp->f_mode & FMODE_READ )
            //handle read opening
   if( filp->f_mode & FMODE_WRITE )
            //handle write opening

   if (MINOR( inode->i_rdev )==2){
      filp->f_op = &my_fops2;
   }

   return 0;
   }
```

how do I use this function from the shell/terminal?

Comment: Whenever you try to use the device the open() will be called. Like `echo "blahblah" > /dev/your_device_node` or `cat /dev/your_device_node`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is either the `open` function for a device driver,
or it’s a sheep in wolf’s clothing [sic]. 
In the unlikely event that this is ordinary, vanilla user-level code,
compile it into an executable and use that.  But if it is a device driver’s `open` function,

- First of all,
  determine whether it is compiled/linked into the currently running kernel. 
  If it isn’t, make it so (compile/link it into the kernel, and reboot).

  - Alternatively,
    you may have the ability to load it into the kernel dynamically. 
    Exactly how to do that depends on your particular operating system
    and is out of scope for this question.
- Find out whether it is a **b**lock device or a **c**haracter device,
  and what its *major* device number is. 
  I can’t tell you specifically how to do that, either;
  consult your local resources.
- OK, let’s suppose that it is a character device with major number 42. 
  Look through `/dev` (with `ls -l`) for entries that begin with `c`
  (for “character”) and contain `42, something`
  where the size should be, like this:

  ```
  drwxr-xr-x  1 root    root        512 Feb 10  2015 .
  drwxr-xr-x  1 root    root       1024 Feb 10  2015 ..
  crw-rw-rw-  1 root    root    42,   0 Aug 15 18:31 foo
  crw-rw-rw-  1 root    root    42,   2 Aug 15 18:31 fu
  crw-rw-rw-  1 root    root    42,  17 Aug 15 18:31 fubar
  ```

  If you can’t find any, create some.  See `man mknod` for details. 
  You should probably create one with minor device number 2
  and at least one with a different number
  (because the code treats 2 as a special case).
- Do to the `/dev/whatever` files whatever you want to,
  based on the intended function of the driver. 
  (Determining the intended function of the driver is out of scope.) 
  For instance, you might try things like

  ```
  od -cb /dev/foo
  echo "Hello, world." > /dev/fu
  ```
- Naturally, if it’s a block device,
  replace `c` in the above instructions with `b`.